# Flutter Unit Test Fails For Right<Failure, List> Equality Expect Check

Tags: flutter

I am a beginner in flutter test and I'm stuck on a unit test for equality.

> expect(result,
> equals(Right<Failure, List>(userTestEntityList)));
>
> Exception has occurred. TestFailure (Expected: **Right<Failure,
> List>:<Right([UserEntity(1, lolo, Laurent, Marin),
> UserEntity(2, roro, Robert, Redford)]**)>   Actual: **Right<Failure,
> List>:**<**Right([UserEntity(1, lolo, Laurent, Marin),
> UserEntity(2, roro, Robert, Redford)**])> )

I have tried two approaches to define the `UserEntity` class:

1. Using Equatable

```dart
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';

class UserEntity extends Equatable {
  const UserEntity({
    this.id,
    this.pseudo,
    this.firstName,
    this.lastName,
  });

  /// A description for id
  final int? id;

  /// A description for pseudo
  final String? pseudo;

  /// A description for firstName
  final String? firstName;

  /// A description for lastName
  final String? lastName;

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [
        id,
        pseudo,
        firstName,
        lastName,
      ];
    
}
```

2. Using operator== and hash overrides

```dart
class UserEntity {
  const UserEntity({
    this.id,
    this.pseudo,
    this.firstName,
    this.lastName,
  });

  /// A description for id
  final int? id;

  /// A description for pseudo
  final String? pseudo;

  /// A description for firstName
  final String? firstName;

  /// A description for lastName
  final String? lastName;


  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) =>
      identical(this, other) ||
      other is UserEntity &&
          runtimeType == other.runtimeType &&
          id == other.id &&
          pseudo == other.pseudo &&
          firstName == other.firstName &&
          lastName == other.lastName;

  @override
  int get hashCode =>
      id.hashCode ^ pseudo.hashCode ^ firstName.hashCode ^ lastName.hashCode;

}
```

Comment: @RandalSchwartz I think those are the two approaches that OP has attempted, and not being used together

Comment: Those two lists can't be equal.  You need to use a list-equality operation.

Answer (score 0):

## Problem:

The test is failing because the two `Right` objects hold two different list objects, which would cause the `==` equality check to fail.

To fix this, you need to do a list equality check, that is, compare the actual elements in both lists to see if they contain the same elements.

## Solution:

There are two ways to solve this problem:

### 1. Directly compare the `Right` values

Directly compare the values of the `Right` objects and use a list equality matcher for the check.

a. If both lists have to be in the same order, use the `orderedEquals` matcher for the check.

```dart
expect(result.value, orderedEquals(userTestEntityList.value))
```

b. If both lists do not necessarily have to be in the same order, use the `unorderedEquals` matcher for the check.

```dart
expect(result.value, unorderedEquals(userTestEntityList.value))
```

### 2. Use a list equality custom `Matcher`

Create a custom `Matcher` that does list equality checks for a `Right<T, List<U>` object.

The custom `Matcher` below demonstrates this and it uses generic types so it can work with any `Left` value or a `List` of any type.

```dart
class RightListEqualsMatcher<T, U> extends Matcher {
  RightListEqualsMatcher(this.expected);

  Right<T, List<U>> expected;

  @override
  Description describe(Description description) {
    return description.add('equals ').addDescriptionOf(expected);
  }

  @override
  bool matches(item, Map matchState) {
    if (item is Right<T, List<U>>) {
      final actualList = item.value;
      final expectedList = expected.value;

      final areBothListsEqual = listEquals(actualList, expectedList);

      return areBothListsEqual;
    }

    return false;
  }
}
```

Use this matcher like this:

```dart
expect(list1, RightListEqualsMatcher(list2));
```